# Is there any way in python for searching pattern from a dataframe and extracting its corresponding values?

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

I have a Dataframe like this.

```
     Area of Power Cons.           Device Name  2016-09-02   2016-09-03  
0   01.11KVA VCB-I South  SJ 11 South Zone Con    32328.19     33157.12   
1   02.11KVA VCB-II Sout  SJ 11 South Zone Con    43879.94     45152.77   
2   03.11 KVA VCB-I Nort  SJ 11 North Zone Con    30132.74     29507.58   
3   04.11 KVA VCB-II Nor  SJ 11 North Zone Con    38632.45 -16448377.89   
4   05.MAIN INCOMER-I So  SJ 11 South Zone Con    31509.76     32313.60   
5   06.MAIN INCOMER-II S  SJ 11 South Zone Con    42617.22     43841.66   
6   07.MAIN INCOMER-I No  SJ 11 North Zone Con    29284.61     28673.92   
7   08.MAIN INCOMER II N  SJ 11 North Zone Con    37391.87     36786.43   
8     22.BLOW ROOM South  SJ 11 South Zone Con     1909.47      1908.40   
9     23.BLOW ROOM North  SJ 11 North Zone Con     1437.14      1369.04   
10      24.CARDING South  SJ 11 South Zone Con     3962.26      3989.94   
11      25.CARDING-North  SJ 11 North Zone Con     3970.63      3706.69   
12   26.PREPRATORY-South  SJ 11 South Zone Con     2456.72      2576.88   
13   27.PREPRATORY-North  SJ 11 North Zone Con     2372.61      2376.38   
14     28.RING FRAME 1-5  SJ 11 South Zone Con     7384.83      7595.06   
15    29.RING FRAME 6-10  SJ 11 South Zone Con     7111.55      7313.15   
16   30.RING FRAME 11-15  SJ 11 South Zone Con     6821.89      7209.26   
17   31.RING FRAME 16-20  SJ 11 South Zone Con     6049.12      6425.47   
18   32.RING FRAME 21-25  SJ 11 North Zone Con     6481.04      6070.30   
19   33.RING FRAME 26-30  SJ 11 North Zone Con     6471.42      6160.90   
20   34.RING FRAME 31-35  SJ 11 North Zone Con     6619.86      6520.43   
21   35.RING FRAME 36-40  SJ 11 North Zone Con     6200.00      6200.00   
22    35.LINC CONER 1-10  SJ 11 South Zone Con     2292.18      2348.64   
23   36.LINC CONER 11-20  SJ 11 South Zone Con     2905.96      2943.62   
24   37.LINC CONER 21-30  SJ 11 North Zone Con     2181.58      2118.38   
25   38.LINC CONER 31-40  SJ 11 North Zone Con     2752.92      2763.26
```

I want to search for the rows which contains `Ring Frame` and get its respective values.

I tried this:

```
df = data[15:22]
```

But I want to search for the names. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thank you for accepting your last question. But it seems you question will be closed, but you can add this code `df['Area'].str.extract('TFO (.*)'))` and some text `you try this, but is is wrong output` for prevent Closing. Thanks and nice day!

Comment: Thanks Jezrael for helping me out. Have a nice day. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with mask where first convert all values to [`lower`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.lower.html) and then use [`contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html):

```
print (df[df['Area of Power Cons.'].str.lower().str.contains('ring frame', na=False)])
```

Another solution with `apply`, but it work only if not `NaN` values:

```
print (df[df['Area of Power Cons.'].apply(lambda x: 'ring frame' in x.lower())])
```

---

If need extract values use [`str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html):

```
print (df['Area of Power Cons.'].str.lower().str.extract('ring frame (.*)'))
```

If all values are uppercase:

```
print (df['Area of Power Cons.'].str.extract('RING FRAME (.*)'))
```

Comment: when i am trying boolean indexing, it is giving a ValueError as ValueError: cannot index with vector containing NA / NaN values

Comment: hi jezrael, i have got one more issue. Suppose, i want to filter only data's of Ring Frame 1-5, then how can we do that? Hope you can help. Thanks.

Comment: You need `print (df[df['Area of Power Cons.'].str.lower().str.contains('ring frame 1-5', na=False)])`

Comment: The output is an empty Dataframe with only the column names.

Comment: I try sample data and for me it works. Can you test sample data?

Comment: And what about `print (df[df['Area of Power Cons.'].apply(lambda x: 'ring frame 1-5' in x.lower())])` ? `-` character is same as in your data?

Comment: 1-5 is in braces like Ring Frame (1-5). Using Lambda, its working but not with the earlier code. Why?

Comment: Ok, so need `print (df[df['Area of Power Cons.'].str.lower().str.contains('ring frame \(1-5\)', na=False)])`

Comment: what return `28.RING FRAME (1-5)`

Comment: Have a nice day. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think regular expressions would be helpfull here as well. You can specify rules for searching with it.

For example you could do something like:

```
import re 
m = re.search('*RING FRAME*')
m.group(0)
```

Note that the  *  wildcard is "greedy", so it will take all previous and following signs into account. I don't exactly know how you store your strings and if they are seperated or not, but you could give it a try with re. 
They are a important python skill to learn by the way (even though I didn't use them a lot myself yet)

You can find more Information on regular expressions in the official python doc: https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html